# Async android returning value into an array

Tags: android

Hi I'm having an issue trying to retrieve information from an async task.

What I'm trying to achieve is get the lng/lat from a postcode and then display them on a map. Getting the lng/lat works fine, its just I cant work out how to get that information from the onPostExecute back to the onCreate in an array.

I can perform a loop to add the map markers there.

Anyone know how I go about this?

**Updated code**

This is the working code that also updates the zoom to fit all entries in. Might help some people out

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.coreoffice.library.GeocodeJSONParser;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds.Builder;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    Button                      mBtnFind;
    static GoogleMap            mMap;
    EditText                    etPlace;

    private static final String TAG     = "MainActivity";
    static ArrayList<Double>    lat     = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static ArrayList<Double>    lng     = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static Builder              bounds  = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_maps);
        Log.v(TAG + "onCreate", "onCreate call");

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();

        String[] location =
        { "WA32ED", "M30oft", "W21AA" }; // address

        String url;

        for (int i = 0; i < location.length; i++)
        {
            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
            url = "";
            url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + location[i] + "&sensor=false";

            Log.v("URL", url);

            downloadTask.execute(url);
        }

    }

    public static void processMap()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lat.size(); i++)
        {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat.get(i), lng.get(i));
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("title");
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            bounds.include(new LatLng(lat.get(i), lng.get(i)));
        }

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 100));
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException
    {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {

        String  data    = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url)
        {
            try
            {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>>
    {
        JSONObject  jObject;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData)
        {
            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            GeocodeJSONParser parser = new GeocodeJSONParser();

            try
            {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                places = parser.parse(jObject);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                MapsActivity.this.lat.add(lat);
                MapsActivity.this.lng.add(lng);

                MapsActivity.processMap();

                Log.v("lat", Double.toString(lat));
                Log.v("lng", Double.toString(lng));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add the `double`s `lat` and `lng` to their respective `ArrayList`s in the `for` loop in `onPostExecute()` of `ParserTask`.

Comment: Cheers for all the answers. Just let me try and get my head around them and try to one to work before I accept an answered. Also with regards to using AsyncTask I was planning on only letting my app run in portrait so there should be a problem with it being recreated all the time but I will have a look at AsyncLoader

Comment: For the life of me I cant get my head around any of these answers! Would anyone be kind enough to rustle me a working code up? been stuck on this for days

Comment: I can't speak for the other answers, but if the code you posted works, i.e. the lat & lng are printing in your LogCat, then all you have to do is add the 3 lines to your `onPostExecute()` in `ParserTask`, create the `processData()` method in the Activity, and do your "loop" in there. Without knowing what you want your "loop" to do, I can't be more specific about the method.

Comment: yeh the lat/log print in the logcat fine. I was just trying add the markers and perform an autozoom in the processData function you suggested

Comment: I edited the original to the updated code

Comment: That looks right. How is it not working?

Comment: It just doesn't display any of the markers

Comment: Are you sure the loop is running, and that there's data in the ArrayLists?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply my internet was playing up. It turned out I wasn't calling processMap() in the onPostExecute. Doh! Its working now tho, just got to work out the auto zooming now. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `AsyncTask`s are, by definition, asynchronous, you cannot guarantee that they will be done before `onCreate()` finishes. You merely need to call a method in `onPostExecute()` of `ParserTask` to handle the "loop" you describe after the tasks have completed.

Your `ArrayList`s `lat` and `lng` are accessible to the inner classes that are your `AsyncTask`s, so you just need to add a few lines to `onPostExecute()`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

        double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

        MapsActivity.this.lat.add(lat);
        MapsActivity.this.lng.add(lng);

        Log.v("lat", Double.toString(lat));
        Log.v("lng", Double.toString(lng));
    }

    processData();
}
```

Then create a method in `MapsActivity`:

```
private void processData()
{
    // Do your loop here.
}
```

Comment: @user3388630, I had made a mistake in my post. I hope you didn't have `processData();` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an `interface` as callback for your `ParserTask` class, and call it in `onPostExecute` method.
First declare an interface:

```
public interface OnParseFinishedListener {
    public void onFinished(/* required params */);
}
```

Then add these methods to your `ParserTask`:

```
public void setOnParseFinishedListener(OnParseFinishedListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

and in your `onPostExecute` add this line:

```
if(listener != null) {
    listener.onFinished(/* pass params here! */);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable to hold your HashMap, and then pass it from your Activity into your AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

1. you Should do the donwloading and parsing in a single asynctask.
2. I would propose using loader instead of asynctask (as you will have a problem once your asynctask returns and your activity has been recreated (eg due to turning the screen or any other configuration change)
3. In onPostExecute you just call a method in your activity. There you can access your map object /fragment (which you store in an instance variable in onCreate).

Again use an asyncloader which behaves very similar to asynctask but will save you a lot of grief down the line even if it's slightly more complex in the beginning.